# не могу принять post/get запрос

Tags: python

Начал изучать python, всё норм только вот сталкнулся с проблемой, как в скрипте принимать запросы? Вот в php:

```
$p = $_POST['lalala'];  
$g = $_GET['lalala'];
```

А в python'е как будет? Вроде бы модуль requests нужен, его скачал, установил себе на хостинг, как отправлять запросы с помощью его понял, получается, а вот как принимать нигде не нашёл

как бы с постом более менее понятно:

```
attat = sys.stdin.read()
```

тут attat будет равен строке запроса... типа login=aaaa&pass=fdfdf но опять же.... это не очень удобно... хотелось бы как в php, на подобие есть решение? но вот с get вообще не знаю как быть

Comment: Может, стоит обратить внимание на какие-нибудь веб-фреймворки? Например, bottle, flask или django.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP **клиент** отправляет http запросы. `requests` это библиотека, которая может помочь в создании http-клиента.

На http запросы такие как GET/POST отвечает http **сервер** (например, apache, nginx, gunicorn), который может запустить Питон код, например, используя [CGI или WSGI интерфейсы](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4929626/4279). Существует множество web frameworks в Питоне, которые предоставляют более высокоуровневый интерфейс, чтобы создать web-приложение, например: [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html), flask, pyramid, django. Также существуют более общие сетевые библиотеки такие как `twisted`, `tornado`, `gevent`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print request.GET['username'] # for GET form method
print request.POST['username'] # for POST form method
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [edit]